# What does [0x200000401:0x4:0x0] for a file ID signify

Tags: centos, filesystems, lustre

I tried to get the id(descriptor) of the file using the `DFID` which is defined as `#define DFID "["DFID_NOBRACE"]"` in lustre and got the output as `[0x200000401:0x4:0x0]`.  So what does the fields separted by `:` in it signify?

Comment: `@Gilles` can you please answer this question?

Answer (score 1):

You can see right next to the definition of `DFID` is the definition of `PFID()`, which is printing the `f_seq`, `f_oid`, and `f_ver` fields of the FID.  FIDs are never re-used within Lustre.

`f_seq` is the 64-bit sequence (SEQ) number.  This indicates on which MDT (or in DNE configurations on which OST) the range of inodes (or objects) it is located.  Each MDT gets a range of sequence numbers, then allocates them (one at a time) to clients, and clients can create new files within that sequence number.

`f_oid` is the 32-bit object ID number (OID).  This indicates an object within the SEQ range, which is allocated by the client whenever a new file is created.  For DNE configurations the MDS allocates OIDs for SEQ numbers assigned to each OST.

`f_ver` is a reserved 32-bit version (VER) field.  This is intended for use by snapshots/datasets to distinguish objects that otherwise have the same SEQ/OID.  This field is also used for OST objects to store the LOV stripe index for a file in the `fid` xattr, so that the LOV layout can be reconstructed from the OST objects if the MDT layout is corrupted.

See https://www.eofs.eu/_media/events/elw11/08_johann_lombardi_hands_on_lustre_2.x.pdf for a more complete description of FIDs.

Answer (score 0):

The first term `0x200000401`.
It is basically the sequence to which the file belongs. In lustre the files belonging to a particular sequence are stored together meaning that all files (objects) with FIDs from a given sequence are stored on the same server.